# Plotting 2D in Python

Tags: python, enthought

I am trying to line plot a function, but I am getting an error. How can I do this?

I am using Enthought [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/).

```
In[35] : plt.plot(np.arange(0, nx, 1), Iftarray[:, ny/2])
Out[35]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x8332dd8>]
```

Comment: This isn't an error, it's the string representation of the result of the function you called.

Answer (score 4):

Like Sam says in the comment: There is no error here; try:

```
plt.show()
```

You'll be surprised :)

Comment: I am getting this error also...dont know why In[53]: pl.imshow
Out[53]: <function matplotlib.pyplot.imshow>

Comment: That isn't an error.  When you use plt.plot() or plt.anythingthatplots without assigning it to a variable then what it returns is outputted to the terminal.  You're seeing that output.  However, in this case you have to give your function arguments.  pl.imshow doesn't do anything, it's just the name of a function.  To see your plot use @cenna75 answer.

Comment: Yes, `.show()` is required initially. Subsequent plots may not need it (even if the plot window is closed).

Answer (score 3):

As the others said, the output text that you see is expected, not an error. However this information, while useful, does not address the question of why you are not seeing the plot.

If your [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) (Canopy's Python shell) is running in Pylab mode (as it does by default; see the Preferences dialog's Python tab to verify), then a plot window should also have been created. However often, depending on the OS, this plot window will not pop up on top of Canopy. So your first task is to poke around your windows and make sure that it's not really there, but you have not seen it.

If the IPython shell is *not* running in Pylab mode, then cenna75's response is correct; the plot won't display until you explicitly tell it to.